# If $X$ is an metric space and $H \subset Iso(X)$, then the function $f(R):= \sup_{g \in H} \sup_{x \in B(p,R/2)} d(g(x),x)$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $X$ is a metric space such that every closed ball is equal to the closure of its respective open ball, then the function $f(R):= \sup_{g \in H} \sup_{ x \in B(p,R/2)} d(g(x),x)$ is continuous, where $p \in X$, $H \subset Iso(X)$ is a subgroup of isometries of $X$ and $B(p,R/2)$ is the open ball of center $p$ and radius $R/2$.

Seeing only the inner sup, it is easy to see that $d(x,g(x)) \leq R + d(p,(g(p))$. Considering an increase of $\delta > 0$ in the radius of the ball, I tried to find a way to maximize the difference $d(g(x),x) - d(g(y),y)$, but I wasn't able to eliminate the terms $R + d(p,(g(p))$ to remain only the term $\delta$. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

After more thought I was able to do part of this.

The sup in $H$ doesn't do much, so let's focus on the inner sup part. Let $x \in B(p, R/2)$ and $y \in B(p, R/2 + \delta/2)$. We have:

$$d(x,y) \geq d(x, g(x)) - d(g(x),y) \geq d(x, g(x)) - d(g(x), g(y)) - d(g(y),y).$$

Since $g$ is an isometry, we obtain that

$$2d(x,y) \geq d(x,g(x)) - d(y,g(y))$$

Similarly, we can show that

$$2d(x,y) \geq d(y,g(y)) - d(x,g(x))$$
therefore
$$ 2d(x,y) \geq |d(x,g(x)) - d(y,g(y))|$$
We can already see that
$$ \sup_{y \in B(p, R/2+ \delta/2)} \inf_{x \in B(p,R/2)} 2d(x,y) \geq \left|\sup_{y \in B(p, R/2+ \delta/2)} d(y,g(y)) - \sup_{x \in B(p,R/2)}d(x,g(x))\right|.$$

For $y \in B(p,R/2)$ the inf is zero, so suppose that $y \notin B(p,R/2)$. All that is needed to complete is to prove that $\inf_{x \in B(p,R/2)} 2d(x,y) \leq \delta$ for that $y$.